# Concept of datatypes representing a value "over time"

Tags: functional-programming, reactive-programming

Going through plethora of reading material over Functional Reactive programming, a very frequently occurring concept is the idea of certain datatypes that represent a value "over time".

What is the basic meaning of this idea? Do we have anything like this in imperative programming?

Comment: Functional programming is all about composing more interesting things from less interesting things, be it functions or data structures. Having a data value that represents a time-varying measure is pretty interesting already.

Comment: I guess we can use the very same datatype representation in imperative programming, but imperatively manipulating it is much more of a hassle especially when we mix the concepts of execution time and represented time.

Comment: So basically value 'over time' take s into account the time factor. Future too...:)?

Comment: The basic idea is that you have types and operations on them that abstract from time, namely `Behavior` and (Event-)`Stream`.

Comment: See Esterel: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esterel